# Why does TensorFlow run significantly faster in Python than in Java on the GPU?

Tags: java, python, performance, tensorflow, gpu

I have trained a TensorFlow model and I have tested it on the GPU in Python and Scala (using the Java API). Running from Java consistently performs worse, clocking in at about half the speed, and I'm wondering why.

The model is a standard text classifier: I am using convolutions with bias over an embedding layer followed by pooling; side-by-side is a fully connected layer with bias and dropout taking additional features; both these gadgets feed into a couple fully connected layers with bias and dropout.

I am classifying microblog text so inputs are small. The slowdown depends on the batch size: processing one input at a time, the two languages perform almost the same; as the batch size increases the gap widens, maxing out at a batch size of 128, where Python performs just under 2x Scala.

The inner loop of the Python code calls:

```
session.run([output], feed_dict)
```

The Scala code similarly calls:

```
session.runner()
    .feed(input1, input1Tensor)
    .feed(input2, input2Tensor)
    .fetch(output)
    .run()
```

I am sure both versions are using the GPU (and can get both to run far slower by running them on the CPU). I have also checked that both languages are providing exactly the same inputs and are receiving the same outputs. I have also profiled the Scala code and found nearly all the time spent in the TensorFlow code above, so there isn't an extraneous portion of the code slowing things down.

I am using Python 3, Scala 2.11, a Java 8 VM, and version 1.2 of the Java TensorFlow API and am running on a Tesla K80 on a Linux server.

I apologize for the vagueness of this question. I'm not sure what details are relevant but would gladly include more specifics upon request.

Comment: IIUC, you're saying that your scala code runs faster than the Java equivalent, even though _both_ are using the same Java API (.jar files and native libraries)?

Do you have timing information for the `run()` calls in Java? Or a pointer to some code to reproduce the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: No one here can comment meaningfully on your benchmarks without knowing the specifics of your benchmark protocols. How did you control for system load? For JVM startup time? Optimization warmup? Degree of GPU use? Other factors? There simply are too many unrevealed unknowns.

Comment: @ash I mean that the Python code ran 2x as fast as the Scala code.

Comment: @LewBloch I apologize for the dearth of information. I can't include my entire code. I will try to create a minimal test case.

Comment: Voting to close as the OP did not fulfill promise to clarify question.

Comment: Did you end up getting any answers to your issue?